# Object of string and () => string values in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i am building a telegram bot 
i want to store all my messages as a constant 
i have a message schema, which looks like

```
type MessagesSchema = {
    [K in keyof typeof MessagesEnum]: string
}
```

and it's implementation as

```
const Messages: MessagesSchema = {
    SOME_KEYS_FROM_ENUM = '123',
    ...
    FUNCTIONAL_VALUE: (a: number) => `The number is ${a}`
}
```

i can't just set values as functions in this constant
how can i rewrite schema to correctly use that?
i tried to set

```
type MessagesSchema = {
    [K in keyof typeof MessagesEnum]: string | ((...params: any) => string)
}
```

but then i need to check is object value callable every time i use this value

```
if(typeof Messages.FUNCTIONAL_VALUE === 'function'){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) with the [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator:

```
const Messages = {
    SOME_KEYS_FROM_ENUM: '123',
    //...
    FUNCTIONAL_VALUE: (a: number) => `The number is ${a}`
} as const satisfies MessagesSchema

Messages.SOME_KEYS_FROM_ENUM
//       ^? "123"
Messages.FUNCTIONAL_VALUE(0) // Okay
//       ^? (a: number) => string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssDO8CGBzBBRc0DeAoKBUAygPIzoD6A0ugJpEUBiASmRegHICqMANPoUZcOAYQAqASRIcAggBkKANXld0uAL65cAFwCeAB2CwEyNPCIBjABbAISKAF4oeQlADaVKAEsQUANbAugD2AGZQeoahxoioGFgAugBcUPDaAE4+KFAAPlAAFHkAdMX6SGlIEPDJSCC6AJSOAHwp6Zl1GloWQSCp0aYIjs4CBKTk1HQMLGycPMkA5ACMAEwAzHP8rgD0m8WFw1BCopLS8koq6Ml5SMlYAEbAaQ0OzQAGYjZQdw-e8FAAJNgkOoXhooEhfl0etoUkhtF54CEvAM4DEzJYbHYtCj+vBCqNKDR6ExWDB2NwYLhtq5CAA9AD8uGxsVxh3EUlkCmUclUeQADA0qSQ-EhdJTNtSCPTcEA)

Comment: didn't pay attention removing `MessagesSchema` after `const Messages` and got errored. removed and all works fine